# How to implement handleUserActivity in WatchOS in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos, apple-watch-complication

I've passed to my `complicationDescriptors` a `userInfo` dictionary that includes the names of my complications so I can be notified of which complication the user tapped on and launch them to that View.  I'm using the new `@App` and `@WKExtensionDelegateAdaptor` for other reasons, so I have access to `handleUserActivity` in my `extensionDelegate` and can unpack the source of the complication tap, but how do I launch them to a specific view in SwiftUI?  `handleUserActivity` [seems to be set up](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextensiondelegate/1628223-handleuseractivity) to work with `WKInterfaceControllers`?

```
class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
        //print("ApplicationDidFinishLanching called")
        
        scheduleNextReload()
        
    }
    
    
    func applicationWillResignActive() {
        //print("applicationWillResignActive called")
    }
    
    func handleUserActivity(_ userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
        
        if let complication = userInfo?[TrackerConstants.complicationUserTappedKey] as? String {
            
            if complication == TrackerConstants.recoveryDescriptorKey {
                //What now?
            } else if complication == TrackerConstants.exertionDescriptorKey {
                //What now?
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same thing. Have you figured it out? Trying to programatically navigate to a new view.

Comment: @alamodey no I was never able to get this to work 

Comment: Are you able to pass through to `handlUserActivity` which complication value is being presented? I have a complication that shows a new value each minute and I can't figure out how to pass which value is being presented.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to update my view according to the tapped complication `userInfo` by using notifications, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64730692/183386).

First declare a notification name:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let complicationTapped = Notification.Name("complicationTapped")
}
```

In your `ExtensionDelegate`:

```
func handleUserActivity(_ userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
    if let complication = userInfo?[TrackerConstants.complicationUserTappedKey] as? String {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(
            name: Notification.Name.complicationTapped,
            object: complication
        )
    }   
}
```

Finally in your view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var activeComplication: String? = nil

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView { // or TabView, etc
        // Your content with NavigationLinks
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
            for: Notification.Name.complicationTapped
        )) { output in
            self.activeComplication = output.object as? String
        }
    }
}
```

For more information on how to activate a view from here, see [Programmatic navigation in SwiftUI](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/swiftui-programmatic-navigation/)

Comment: Are your complications also using SwiftUI? I can't get handleUserActivity to get called for some reason.